# Model.create and Model.collection.insert both don't completely save object

Tags: node.js, csv, mongoose

I have a Node JS project with Mongoose connecting to a MongoDB collection.

I want the user to be able to upload a csv export of this collection and have its content be the content of the MongoDB. I make the export using mongoose-csv.

EDIT: I do the csv parsing using fast-csv

Here is a snippet:

```
//import a csv file into the database
app.post('/importdatabase', function (req, res) {


    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {

        csv.fromStream(file, { headers : true }).on("data", function (data) {

            //Clear Database
            License.remove({}, function (err) {

                //Check for errors
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                }

            });

            //Insert uploaded database

            console.log(data);

            License.collection.insert(data);

        }).on("end", function () {
            console.log("done");

            //Send user back to main page
            res.writeHead(301, {
                'Location': '/',
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            });
            res.end();
        });

    });


    req.pipe(req.busboy);

});
```

I am testing with a collection of 4 documents. When I use the License.collection.insert method, it only saves the last item to the collection. When I use the License.create method, it only saves the last 3 items.

When I make a log of the incoming 'data', it shows all 4 items. What can I do to debug this further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to put the `insert` inside the `remove` callback:

```
csv.fromStream(file, {
    headers: true
}).on("data", function(data) {

    //Clear Database
    License.remove({}, function(err) {

        //Check for errors
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        //Insert uploaded database

        console.log(data);

        License.collection.insert(data);
    });

}).on("end", function() {
    console.log("done");

    //Send user back to main page
    res.writeHead(301, {
        'Location': '/',
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    res.end();
});
```